# preg_match() checks only last character

Tags: php, preg-match

I have the following code which makes some incorrect regex:

```
$newPw = 'aaaAAAaaA';

$low = preg_match("/^(?:.*[a-z].*[a-z])+$/", $newPw); // at least two lowercases
$up = preg_match("/^(?:.*[A-Z])+$/", $newPw);  // at least one uppercase
$sc = preg_match("/^(?:.*[!@#$%^&*].*[!@#$%^&*])+$/", $newPw);  // at least two special characters


if (!$low) {
    echo 'Password must contain at least two lowercases';
} else if (!$up) {
    echo 'Password must contain at least one uppercase';
} else if (!$sc) {
    echo 'Password must contain at least two special characters';
} else echo 'ok';
```

The problem is that my preg_matches cheks only the last character.For example,if **$newPw** is **aaA** it asks for two lowecases,but if **$newPw** is **aaAa** it asks for one upercase.Both of them are wrong,and i can't figure where is the problem.

First I had all preg_matches combined in only one big preg_match.After I split them,it returned errors above

**SOLVED** It was so simple that i am ashamed.The solution is justto remove **^** from the start and the **+$** from the end of each preg_match.

Comment: `^.*(?=.{4,10})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*$` ?

Comment: It checks the whole string, but remove ^ from start and $ from end

Comment: @JoniSalmi

Oo..it was so simple...i am so silly.so the answer is just the remove ^ and +$ and it works well.

Comment: As a side not, the more strict you make your password requirements (apart from length) the easier it will be to brute force.

Comment: @AdiCrainic: Please do not add "solved" to your question title. If one of the answers helped you to solve the problem, [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/220538) by clicking the check mark in the left margin. If none of the answers were useful and you figured out a solution of your own, post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pattern for two lowercase characters:

> /.*[a-z]+.*[a-z]+/

This will return the entire string if there is at least two lowercase letters but I guess that is no problem becouse you only check if it's true;

The problem was that you didn't have any quantifier (+ = 1 or more) after the brackets, so it wasn't clear for regex how many times should the class definition be checked ([a-z] lowercahse character class definition). Outer brackets are unnecessary becouse we don't need sub pattern now.

Pattern for at least one uppercase letter:

> /.*[A-Z]+.*/

The same applies, it returns the entire string, but only if it has at least one uppercase letter in it.

Pattern for at least two special chars:

> /.*[!@#$%^&*]+.*[!@#$%^&*]+.*/

I like pre testing some PHP functions using this site (link to preg_match):

http://www.functions-online.com/preg_match.html

I think it is really helpful sometimes.
I hope I helped!